# get bitmap from textview in android

Tags: android, uiview, bitmap, draw

I want to get the bitmap that is drawn when a textview is displayed but without displaying the textview in the activity. something like this:

```
TextView t = new TextView(this);
t.forceToDrawItself();
Bitmap b=t.getViewBitmap();
```

how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`View#draw(Canvas)`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)) will draw the entire view into the given `Canvas`. You can use the constructor [`Canvas(Bitmap)`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)) to create a Canvas that draws into the given `Bitmap`.

Create a bitmap of the desired size with [`Bitmap#createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap.Config)`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)), wrap it in a canvas, and pass it to your view's `draw` method.

Comment: ok works fine. now i have the problem that i have to set the size of the view manually.. is there a method to calc the default size of a view? like t.initSize(); ?

Comment: Take a look at the "Layout" section of the View class documentation. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) You will want to call View#measure with MeasureSpecs for width and height.

Comment: It helped me. But I'm facing one problem. I need to center align the text. I tried setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) but it's not giving the required output. Any suggestions?