# Android Peformance Optimization - How to draw a cached bitmap back to a textview

Tags: android, performance, caching, optimization, bitmap

Basically, I want to cache a frequently drawn text view to increase the performance of my application.

So, on first-time draw, I cached the text view into a bitmap type buffer, using the methodology in these posts - [get bitmap from textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033107/get-bitmap-from-textview-in-android) & [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android?lq=1)

Now, on subsequent draw requests, I want to draw the saved bitmap buffer back to a text view.

But, I am not able to find specimen code for that. There is a lot of discussion on SO for saving a bitmap from the textview, but not much regarding drawing the bitmap back to text view !
Please help me if anybody has worked in this area before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the bitmap into a drawable object and then use the setBackroung method.

```
Bitmap mBitmap;
Drawable mDrawable=new new BitmapDrawable(mBitmap) 
textView.setBackground(mDrawable);
```

But, his method is deprecated. You might save your bitmap into resources as android documention suggests.

Comment: As stated in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978884/bitmapdrawable-deprecated-alternative, we can use the alternative version of the deprecated constructor - BitmapDrawable(bitmap) which is BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

> When loading a bitmap into an ImageView, the LruCache is checked first. If an entry is found, it is used immediately to update the ImageView, otherwise a background thread is spawned to process the image: ....

Comment: This code will load the saved bitmap to an image view. But I want to be able to load it into a text-view !